# Проблема выполнения mysql запроса

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, prompt

Есть задача - после нажатия кнопки вывести prompt , который передаст в переменную значение для удаления записи в **mysql**. Работает до момента выполнения самого запроса. После вывода сообщения, переменной `$a` присваивается нужное значение, но не выполняется запрос в базе. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<form action="Otchet.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Удалить запись" name="but1">
</form>
<?php
    function prompt($prompt_msg){
        echo("<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = prompt('".$prompt_msg."'); </script>");
        $answer = "<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(answer); </script>";
        return($answer);
    }

    //program
    if (!empty($_POST['but1'])){
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Error podkl");
    $db=mysql_select_db("r20i", $link) or die ("Error podkl k bd");
    $prompt_msg = "Какую запись удалить?";
    $a = prompt($prompt_msg);
    $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM r20i.ledenec WHERE id='$a'",$link);
    if ($result!="") {echo "Запись удалена";} else {echo "Ошибка удаления!";};
    mysql_close($link);};

?>
```

**php** выполняется только после нажатия на кнопку. Код примерно работает, но всегда выводит "Ошибка удаления!"

Comment: а вы смотрели, что возвращается в `$result` и какой запрос формируется при `"DELETE FROM r20i.ledenec WHERE id='$a'"` - пробовали его руками в БД вызвать?

Comment: Я так понимаю , что переменная А выполняется на стороне клиента и ее нужно отправить в MySQL, чтобы запрос выполнила на стороне сервера

Comment: А! Точно! У вас скорее всего php вообще ломается в этом месте. Вам значение $a надо получать в POST запросе. Т.е. у клиента спрашивать значение, записывать его в какой нибудь input и уже отправлять форму.

Comment: Не подскажешь как записать эту переменную в какой-нибудь type=hidden , а потом методом POST отправить обратно в php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На стороне клиента надо сделать вот такую форму со скрытым полем, в которое будет передано значение из prompt

```js
    function send() {
        document.getElementById('hid').value = prompt('Кого удаляем?')
    }
```

```html
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id="hid" name="hid" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" onclick="send()">
</form>
```

А на сервере делать так:

```
$a = $_POST['hid'];
```

Тогда в переменную **$a** будет подставлено нужное значение, которое и уйдет в **SQL** запросе.